# Kotlin Realm create object

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, realm

I want to create a new Stock object in the database using the createObject method. The object is created, but all fields have default values. What am I doing wrong?

```
open class Stock (
    @PrimaryKey var stockId: String = UUID.randomUUID().toString(),
    var stockSymbol: String = "",
    var stockPrice: Double = 0.0
): RealmObject()


val realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance()
realm.executeTransaction { realm ->
    val stock = realm.createObject(Stock::class.java, UUID.randomUUID().toString())
    stock.stockSymbol = "str"
    stock.stockPrice = 2.0
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code,
[documentation](https://realm.io/blog/realm-4-3-0-released-w-first-class-support-for-kotlin/)

```
realm.executeTransaction { realm ->
    val stock = realm.createObject<Stock>(UUID.randomUUID().toString())
    stock.stockSymbol = "str"
    stock.stockPrice = 2.0
}
```

Comment: This throws an error: io.realm.exceptions.RealmException: 'Stock' has a primary key, use 'createObject(Class<E>, Object)' instead.

I also tried `val stock = realm.createObject<Stock>(UUID.randomUUID().toString())` 
also creates a default object

Comment: https://github.com/realm/realm-java/blob/master/examples/kotlinExample/src/main/kotlin/io/realm/examples/kotlin/KotlinExampleActivity.kt